# Reading Date From Different String Formats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, string, date

Is there any build-in javascript function, where I can use another string format to initialize date.

Such as, instead of this:

```
new Date (1988,0,1);
```

I want to use something like:

```
new Date (19880101,"yyyymmdd");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is 'no'   javascript does not have a 'built in' function for formating a date witha  request string.

Easy enough to write one though...